# How to add custom fields in WordPress "Add a New Post" page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add a custom field on Add A New Post page.

Like - if I am to make a plugin which will post links to Twitter after a new post is made, I would like to give ability to user to select if he wants to tweet that particular post's link to Twitter. I want to display a check box somewhere in the page which says - "Post this on Twitter" and then check for it and make a tweet.

I have seen some plugins which do this. But can't remember which they were.

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have finally figured how to achieve this

You can use these hooks -

submitpost_box  } To display fields/form 
submitpage_box }

edit_post  } To process the form
edit_page }

Hope that helps!

Source - Kontera ContentLink WordPress plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the `add_meta_box()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this very helpful plugin to add custom fields.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/more-fields/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this plugin can help you?
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tweet-this/

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I wanted to do something. That was just for an example. I have found how to do that and I am gonna post code soon. :-)